How to compare ranks for individual items across multiple lists using statistical tests?
I have multiple ranked lists for the same items, I want to compare the ranks of a specific item across two subsets of the lists and assess the statistical significance, what statistical tests I should be using? can I simply perform t-test on the ranks although their distribution is not normal?
For example, in the dummy dataset df:
> set.seed(123)
> df <- data.frame(replicate(n = 6, expr = sample(1:10, 10, replace = FALSE)))
> rownames(df) <- paste0("Item", LETTERS[1:10])

> df
      X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
ItemA  3 10  8  7  7  2
ItemB 10  5  7  5  5  1
ItemC  2  3  2  4 10  9
ItemD  8  8  1 10  9  3
ItemE  6  1  6  2  3  8
ItemF  9  4  3  9  1  5
ItemG  1  6  4  3  2  7
ItemH  7  9 10  1  8  6
ItemI  5  7  9  8  6  4
ItemJ  4  2  5  6  4 10

I want to see if the rankings are different for ItemF between two subsets (columns 1,2,3 vs columns 4,5,6). Can I do:
> t.test(df["ItemF", 1:3], df["ItemF", 4:6])

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  df["ItemF", 1:3] and df["ItemF", 4:6]
t = 0.11251, df = 3.823, p-value = 0.9161
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -8.044952  8.711619
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 5.333333  5.000000 


Do you only have 10 items in your actual data? How many lists are in each group (ballpark)?

My original dataset is a gene set, so actually over 10,000 items (genes) in more than 10 samples (lists)

With enough data, plus some reasonable assumptions, the means of even non-normal variables will have a normal distribution. Thus, it's not the potential lack of normality that is concerning here, but the small sample size ($N \approx 10$, since you only care about a single gene).
In this situation, I would try a permutation test. Permutation tests are based on the idea of scrambling/permuting the group flag
in many or all possible ways, calculating the value of a test statistic for each permutation, and taking this set of values of the statistic as the null distribution. If the difference you observe is as or more extreme relative to that distribution, that is strong evidence against the null.
There are $\binom{6}{3} = \frac{6!}{3!(6-3)!} = 20$ possible permutations with six samples putting 3 in each group, so it's easy to consider them all. Here's an example in Stata, using the Welch's t-test and its regression analog:
. clear

. input str1 gene int(X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6)

          gene        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        X6
  1. "A"  3 10  8  7  7  2
  2. "B" 10  5  7  5  5  1
  3. "C"  2  3  2  4 10  9
  4. "D"  8  8  1 10  9  3
  5. "E"  6  1  6  2  3  8
  6. "F"  9  4  3  9  1  5
  7. "G"  1  6  4  3  2  7
  8. "H"  7  9 10  1  8  6
  9. "I"  5  7  9  8  6  4
 10. "J"  4  2  5  6  4 10
 11. end

. reshape long X, i(gene) j(sample)
(j = 1 2 3 4 5 6)

Data                               Wide   ->   Long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of observations               10   ->   60          
Number of variables                   7   ->   3           
j variable (6 values)                     ->   sample
xij variables:
                           X1 X2 ... X6   ->   X
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. rename X rank

. sort gene sample

. sencode gene, replace label(gene)

. order sample

. gen group = inrange(sample,1,3)

. keep if gene == "F":gene
(54 observations deleted)

. // equivalent t-test and regression
. ttest rank, by(group) unequal reverse

Two-sample t test with unequal variances
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Group |     Obs        Mean    Std. err.   Std. dev.   [95% conf. interval]
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
       1 |       3    5.333333    1.855921     3.21455   -2.652052    13.31872
       0 |       3           5    2.309401           4   -4.936551    14.93655
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
Combined |       6    5.166667    1.327069    3.250641    1.755328    8.578005
---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff |            .3333333    2.962731               -8.044952    8.711619
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    diff = mean(1) - mean(0)                                      t =   0.1125
H0: diff = 0                     Satterthwaite's degrees of freedom =  3.82297

    Ha: diff < 0                 Ha: diff != 0                 Ha: diff > 0
 Pr(T < t) = 0.5420         Pr(|T| > |t|) = 0.9161          Pr(T > t) = 0.4580

. reg rank i.group if gene=="F":gene, vce(robust)

Linear regression                               Number of obs     =          6
                                                F(1, 4)           =       0.01
                                                Prob > F          =     0.9158
                                                R-squared         =     0.0032
                                                Root MSE          =     3.6286

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
        rank | Coefficient  std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     1.group |   .3333333   2.962731     0.11   0.916    -7.892528    8.559195
       _cons |          5   2.309401     2.17   0.096    -1.411925    11.41193
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. // Monte Carlo permutation test versions
. permute group (diff:_b[1.group]), enumerate nowarning : reg rank i.group, vce(robust)
(running regress on estimation sample)
(enumerating all 20 possible permutations)

Permutations (20): ..........10..........20 done

Enumeration permutation results

Number of observations =  6
Number of permutations = 20

Permutation variable: group

      Command: regress rank i.group, vce(robust)
  [diff]_pm_1: _b[1.group]

----------------------------------------------------------
           T |    T(obs)       Test       c       n      p
-------------+--------------------------------------------
diff         |
       _pm_1 |  .3333333      lower      12      20  .6000
             |                upper      10      20  .5000
             |            two-sided                 1.0000
----------------------------------------------------------
Notes: For lower one-sided test, c = #{T <= T(obs)} and p = p_lower = c/n.
       For upper one-sided test, c = #{T >= T(obs)} and p = p_upper = c/n.
       For two-sided test, p = 2*min(p_lower, p_upper).

. permute group (diff:(r(mu_1) - r(mu_2))), enumerate nowarning : ttest rank, by(group) unequal reverse
(running ttest on estimation sample)
(enumerating all 20 possible permutations)

Permutations (20): ..........10..........20 done

Enumeration permutation results

Number of observations =  6
Number of permutations = 20

Permutation variable: group

      Command: ttest rank, by(group) unequal reverse
  [diff]_pm_1: r(mu_1) - r(mu_2)

----------------------------------------------------------
           T |    T(obs)       Test       c       n      p
-------------+--------------------------------------------
diff         |
       _pm_1 |  .3333333      lower      12      20  .6000
             |                upper      10      20  .5000
             |            two-sided                 1.0000
----------------------------------------------------------
Notes: For lower one-sided test, c = #{T <= T(obs)} and p = p_lower = c/n.
       For upper one-sided test, c = #{T >= T(obs)} and p = p_upper = c/n.
       For two-sided test, p = 2*min(p_lower, p_upper).

The two-sided p-value in the regular test is 0.9161 (matching your R output). The permute exact p-value is 1. This means that while the lower average rank in group 1 is suggestive, you cannot reject the null of no difference in means. The permute p-value is as far as you can get from zero.
You could have also permuted the outcome, keeping group membership fixed: it does not really matter here for the results, but scrambling group will be speedier since 20 < 360.
You can also try the two-sample Wilcoxon rank-sum (Mann-Whitney) test. Ranks of ranks are a tad confusing, but the test gives the same exact result as above and will be faster:
. ranksum rank, by(group) exact porder

Two-sample Wilcoxon rank-sum (Mann–Whitney) test

       group |      Obs    Rank sum    Expected
-------------+---------------------------------
           0 |        3        10.5        10.5
           1 |        3        10.5        10.5
-------------+---------------------------------
    Combined |        6          21          21

Unadjusted variance        5.25
Adjustment for ties       -0.15
                     ----------
Adjusted variance          5.10

H0: rank(group==0) = rank(group==1)
         z =  0.000
Prob > |z| = 1.0000
Exact prob = 1.0000

P{rank(group==0) > rank(group==1)} = 0.500

It also returns the probability that in a random draw of one from each group, the rank (of ranks) for group 0 will be greater than for group 1. This is half: effectively, it is a fair coin toss.
